# Solve trigonometric inequality $2\cos^2x+\cos(2x) \geq 1$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, solution-verification

Can I solve it this way?

$2\cos^2x+\cos^2x-\sin^2x \ge \sin^2x+\cos^2x$

$2\cos^2x-2\sin^2x \ge 0$

$2(\cos^2x-\sin^2x) \ge 0$

$2\cos(2x) \ge 0$

$\cos(2x) \ge 0$

Comment: It 's correct! Can you go for the next step?

Comment: Slightly more to the point: $$2\cos^{2}\left(x\right)+\cos\left(2x\right)\geq1\\
(2\cos^{2}\left(x\right)-1)+\cos\left(2x\right)\geq0\\
2\cos\left(2x\right)\geq0$$

Comment: It's good to remeber the identity $\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1$.

Comment: So, the ending interval is [-pi/4 + npi , pi/4 + npi]?

Comment: The solution set can be denoted $[-\pi/4,\,\pi/4]+\pi\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

You ended up with $\cos 2x\ge 0\tag 1$

This is possible if and only if $2x$ is in either first or the fourth quadrant. In particular,$(1)$ is true if $2x \in  \color{blue}{[0, \frac \pi 2]\cup [\frac {3\pi} 2,2\pi]}$.

To generalize the blue colored domain, just add $2n\pi, n\in \mathbb Z$ to get the following:

$2x\in [2n\pi, 2n\pi+\frac \pi 2] \cup [ 2n\pi+\frac{3\pi}2, 2n\pi +2\pi], n\in \mathbb Z$.

It follows that $x\in [n\pi, n\pi+\frac \pi 4]\cup [n\pi+\frac{3\pi}4, n\pi +\pi], n\in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score -1):

$$2\cos^2 x + \cos 2x \ge 1\implies 2\cos^2x + 2\cos^2x - 1\ge 1 \implies \cos^2x \ge \frac 12$$

$$\frac 1{\sqrt2} \le \cos x \text{ or }\cos x \le -\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$$
Solving both
$-\frac 1{\sqrt2} \ge \cos x$ and $\cos x \ge\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$

$\color{blue}{x \in \left[n\pi-\frac {\pi}{4}, n\pi+\frac {\pi}{4}\right]}$ where $n\in \mathbb Z$

---

- @maths0 comments: using $\cos 2x $

$2\cos^2x  + \cos 2x \ge 1 \implies \cos 2x + 1  + \cos 2x \ge 1 \implies \cos 2x \ge 0$

Instead of solving this problem let's try to understand what exactly it means when $\cos 2x \ge 0$

In short $\cos 2x \ge 0 \implies \text{ cos 2x should be positive and $2x$ must lie in 1st and 4rth quadrant}$
$2x  =  \text{even multiply of }\pi \pm \frac {\pi}{2}$

$x = n\pi \pm \frac {\pi}{4}$

[On page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLjBj.jpg)

Comment: What does $\mathbb{I}$ stand for?!

Comment: @DarshanP. Dear friend, I didn't do that. :)

Comment: I don't understand, can this inequality be solved in different ways, because how did you get cos²x≥1/2

Comment: Dear downvoters, Downvotes are welcomed but please don't forget to comment! bcz I still don't understand if the answer is not right I also checked on [geogebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXgWn.png)

Comment: Your first solution is wrong.  You correctly obtained $\cos^2x \geq \frac{1}{2}$.  However, that implies that $|\cos x| \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \implies \cos x \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or $\cos x \leq -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks got that I have had made a very silly mistake!!! *Updated*

Comment: The first boldface and should be an or since $\cos x$ cannot simultaneously be both $\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\leq -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.  Otherwise, your solution is now correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks a lot mann! though If I still have left any mistake let this answer be downvoted so that I can remember I'll take it as a lesson!